# Problem with reading data from I2C Temperature Sensor with stm32

Tags: sensor, stm32, i2c

Hi I'm pretty to new to embedded programming and unfortunatly I faced a problem when trying to do an excercise with STM32F103RBT6 Nucleo 64 Board and LPS25HB temperature/pressure sensor. I try to read the output value from a sensor (which is then converted to temperature), but I'm still getting the wrong value. Here's my simple code for this:

```
  uint8_t t_buffer = 0;
  uint16_t temperature_buffer = 0;

  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */

    temperature_buffer = read_lps_reg(TEMP_OUT_H);
    temperature_buffer = (temperature_buffer << 8);
    t_buffer = read_lps_reg(TEMP_OUT_L);
    temperature_buffer = temperature_buffer | (uint16_t)(t_buffer);

    printf("T = %.1f*C\n", 42.5f + temperature_buffer / 480.0f);

    HAL_Delay(2000);

  }
```

I use HAL library and 'read_lps_reg' is just my function to read from device using I2C with HAL - it definitely works, because at the beginning I always try to read the device address and check if it's correct. The sensor works the way, that it stores the output value in two separate registers, what you can see in a screen from its datasheet below:
[image]

So while the debugging my program I get results like this:
[image]

[image]

So as you can see in a debugger, at the end I get a correct value in decimal (-9955, I checked and after putting this into the formula, which is presented in 'printf(...)' statement, it's the correct value which I should get), but it seems, that compiler takes the default value which is 55581 - the difference is because, the value of both registers are expressed as 2's complement, as stated in screens from datasheet, which I put above. Did anybody of you have maybe a similar situation or could help mi out with this? I've been struggling for a while with this and don't know what to do.

Comment: I suppose the compiler wants to represent it as unsigned number, since you declared it as uint.

Comment: ABC, take a closer look at your formula in the printf(). How does the C compiler parse it? Think closely. Think about how ***you*** would process it, keeping in mind that the variable is an ***unsigned int***. If you wanted a signed value, then you need to tell the C compiler that your unsigned int is really a signed int. Not so? (Otherwise, the C compiler will interpret it as an unsigned value and convert it to floating point as a positive float value before performing the division.)

Comment: ABC, just use: **42.5f + ((int16_t) temperature_buffer) / 480.0f**

Comment: ABC, I think I must still give you +1 as you more than adequately documented your question. I was able to immediately spot where to look because of the work you put in. So thanks! I appreciate it when I see questions done up like this.

Comment: @jonk thank you very much! The problem was apparently so obvious and simple that I was just looking for it to deep. Thanks again.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič thank you very much too. Unfortunately in response I can notify only one user, so I had to mention you in second comment. Thanks again!

Comment: @ABC Keep in mind that the C standard (last time I looked, which was admittedly a decade back or more) does ***not*** provide a guarantee for conversion from an unsigned int to a signed int (of the same physical memory size) when the values are more positive than the maximum positive value of the signed int. In practice, this is never a problem as C compiler writers don't want to intentionally do mean things to folks. But as a technical C standard issue, a C compiler writer could, while staying true to the standard, decide to test and then generate random values for the indicated cases. ;)

Comment: @ABC If you want to write code that fits the standard while also forcing what you want in the face of C compiler writers who have it as their personal mission to make your life harder, then you would need to compose a union in order to defeat them. :)